# Alpine container not able to resolve hostname

Tags: kubernetes, alpine-linux

I have a StatefulSet Kubernetes deployment with 2 worker nodes. I was able to bring the containers up on those 2 nodes using a headless service hence the nodes have hostname as

- abc-0.abc.default.svc.cluster.local
- abc-1.abc.default.svc.cluster.local

The problem is that I am **not** able to ping abc-0 from abc-1 and in the opposite direction using the hostname. If I use IP addresses then everything works fine.

There were issues related the DNS resolution with Alpine Linux at some point(https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/8#issuecomment-172594887) but seems it was fixed in Alpine Linux 3.4.

What would be the good way to verify that the problem I am facing is not because of the Linux but instead some misconfiguration in Kube-DNS or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the service I was running didn't get endpoints assigned to it. I am using v1.7.3 so resolved the problem by adding 'selector' on the headless service. Also, looks like this is no longer a problem in v1.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `ping abc-0`, did you try `ping abc-0.abc` ?
The resolv.conf is not enriched with all the statefull service entries search domains, just the namespace one, so when you try to access by only `abc-0` it actually resolves to `abc-0.default.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: As you mentioned, I do see the following search domains in the resolv.conf:
- default.svc.cluster.local 
- svc.cluster.local 
- cluster.local
After login into the node where abc-0 is running:
- `ping abc-0` works fine
- `ping abc-0.abc` returns bad address error
- `ping abc-1` returns bad address error
- `ping abc-1.abc` returns bad address error